# How to make form action to work?

Tags: joomla-3.x, form

I'm learning how to make my own module on Joomla. 
MyModule **mod_planejamentomensal.php** is like this:

```
//No direct access 
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/helper.php';

Jhtml::_('jquery.framework');
Jhtml::_('jquery.ui');
JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidator');
JHtml::script(JURI::base() . '/modules/mod_planejamentomensal/js/jquery-3.3.1.js');
JHtml::script(JURI::base() . '/modules/mod_planejamentomensal/js/jquery.mask.js');
```

**default.php** has my form (with some other fileds and jQuery, I'm copying part of it here so it won't be too long):

```
 <div class="planj-mensal-form">
  <form method="post" name="frmCasdastra" class="form-validate" action="<?php JURI::base() . '/modules/mod_planejamentomensal/tmpl/adicionaForm.php' ?>">
    <div class="divTable">
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableColumn">
                <b>Solicitação nº:</b> <?php //echo $solicitacaoTemp; ?>
            </div>
        </div>


      <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableColumn divTableColumn1">
                <b>Agência:</b> <?php echo $grupo; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="divTableColumn divTableColumn2">
                <div class="divLabel"><label for="mes">Mês Referência:</label></div>
                <div class="divInput">
                <select name="mes">
                <?php 
                    $select = $planMensal->setSelect($mes, 'mes', date('m',strtotime('+1 month'))); 
                    echo $select;
                ?>
                </select>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
            <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divtableColumnBotao">
                <div class="divInput">
                    <input name="add" type="button" value="Adicionar mais um formulário" id="add">
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>  
</div>
```

So, my form action above points to **adicionaForm.php** wich is like:

```
<?php

 defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$input = new JInput;
$teste = $input->get('mes',null);

echo "Show: ".$teste;
?>
```

But when I click on submit button nothing happens...I Know there must be something on Joomla that I'm doing wrong. I tried to read documentation for forms but I didn't understand much of it. Can anyone please give me a hint?

Comment: Importing your own version of jQuery is going to lead to all sorts of issues. I strongly suggest you dont. There's no reason to do that when you only require a `mask` plugin. Find a vanilla Javascript one and you'll be good to go ;)

Comment: FYI: For stability in "next month" generation, read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41952314/2943403).  And if you are only using `$select` once, don't bother declaring the variable, just `echo` the returned value.

Comment: Thank you for your tips, @mickmackusa! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Without "JURI::base() ." it worked!!

Comment: For the record, `for="mes"` will be looking for a corresponding `id="mes"`.  In other words, `for` does not related to `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `type="button"` to `type="submit"`.

From [Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button):

> `<input type="button">` elements have no default behavior (their
>   cousins, `<input type="submit">` and `<input type="reset">` are used to
>   submit and reset forms, respectively). To make buttons do anything,
>   you have to write JavaScript code to do the work.

and

> Note: While `<input>` elements of type "button" are still perfectly
>   valid HTML, the newer `<button>` element is now the favored way to
>   create buttons. Given that a `<button>`’s label text is inserted between
>   the opening and closing tags, you can include HTML in the label, even
>   images.

Comment: I can't believe it worked! I would never guess thtat! Thank you so much!